# Unable to get Kafka working due to address issue

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to follow a cloud guru course on kafka but when I setup the server and try and run it I get this error in the kafka server.log file:

```
WARN Cannot open channel to 2 at election address zoo2/172.31.21.241:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
```

It looks wrong as it seems to be putting the ip address after the name that I have defined in the host file shown below

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

172.31.30.11 zoo1 blaaaa.mylabserver.com
172.31.21.241 zoo2
172.31.22.75 zoo3

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

My zookeeper.properties file looks like this, it previously had the 0.0.0.0 as zoo1 but read somewhere that it could cause an issue but still no luck getting it working.

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have corrected the issue, it would seem that I had to explicitly allow the ports as follows

Check what firewall ports are open

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Add the following ports

```
sudo ufw allow 2888
sudo ufw allow 3888
sudo ufw allow 9092
sudo ufw allow 2181
```